# React axios post request does not send the data

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-post

I am using react for my app. I am learning post request. I found one dummy api site [Mocky](https://designer.mocky.io/design) where I can test my post request. This is my api [link](https://run.mocky.io/v3/15c2b7ec-9f31-4a18-ae60-a7f41e1f39b2) .For post request I used `axios`. I don't know how the Mocky api works. I made post request. when I console log the input values I can the value.But when I console log the response it seems like it does not get the data. I don't see any where I am making mistake.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { API_URLS } from '../utilities';
import axios from "axios";
export default function CreateAccount() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    "email": ``,
    "password": ``,
    "loading": false,
    "error": ``
  });
  const onChangeStudent = (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
    const url = `https://run.mocky.io/v3/15c2b7ec-9f31-4a18-ae60-a7f41e1f39b2`;
    const obj = {
      "email": state.email,
      "password": state.password
    };
    console.log(obj.email); //I can see the input value
    console.log(obj.password);//I can see the input value
    axios
      .post(url, obj)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data); // it does not show the data
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          "error": error
        });
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={state.name}
          onChange={onChangeStudent}
          id="email"
          required
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          value={state.password}
          onChange={onChangeStudent}
          id="password"
          required
        />
        <button
          className="btn waves-effect blue lighten-1"
          type="submit"
          name="action"
          disabled={state.loading}
        >
          {state.loading ? `loading...` : `save`}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi can't seem to find anything wrong with what you are doing.

I tested the below and it worked for me. Try to change from .then to await. Hope this solves your problem. Check in your network tab if your request is successful and if you are sending the body.

```
try {
       const response = await axios.post('https://run.mocky.io/v3/4b95050f-2bcc-4c78-b86e-6cac09372dce', data);
       console.log("Response", response);
     } catch(e) {
         console.error(e);
     }
```

Comment: Thank you mate. stupid mocky site confused me. I figure it out now :).

Comment: If my answer helped you. Mark it as the answer. Otherwise what did you do to make it work?